# Windows Authentication Single Sign-On with SQL Server and Liquibase?

Tags: sql-server, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, liquibase, jtds

Liquibase requires a username and password as parameters. Has anyone been able to get Windows domain authentication to their SQL Server database with Single Sign-on working with their Liquibase installation?

We're using jtds as our JDBC driver, which claims to support Windows domain single sign-on in their `README.SSO` file in the release. They also include a helpful example of how to use it. For reference, we're using SQL Server 2012.

However, when I attempt to login with the username parameter set, it has a login failure for the username passed.

When I attempt to login with the username parameter blank, it complains

> Could not parse '--username'

Anyone have any luck with this?

Comment: What happens when you leave out the `--username` and `--password` altogether? The documentation says it is required but looking at the command line parser in the `3.0` sources of liquibase I could not find this to be true (I just looked at the sources - I do not have a test scenario to really prove this.)
Also, what version of liquibase are you using? And: Does the SSO mechanism work manually (without liquibase)?

Comment: I figured this out by trial and error. The command line documentation does appear to be wrong. I was actually able to leave off the --username and --password, but now I'm getting errors from the jtds JDBC. "java.io.IOException: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property."

I can clearly see from others who have seen the same message that the solution should be to put the JTDS 32-bit ntlmauth.dll file in the JAVA_HOME\bin directory (for my 32-bit OS), but this does not appear to be working.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is more of a jtds problem then - which I have no knowledge about. I have added the jtds tag to your question but maybe it would be better to ask another (more specific) question for the jtds problem.